# Executing streaming query method in a class that implements Runnable in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot application that executes multiple threads when receiving a post request. In one of the threads, I stream data from db. To run it as its own thread, the class containing streaming query method implements Runnable class. The demo code is as follows:

**Contorller**

```
    @Autowired
    private DemoJPA demoJPA;

    @PostMapping("/demoPost")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doPost() {
        try {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new DemoClass(demoJPA));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new AnotherClass());
            t2.start();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Demo class**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoClass implements Runnable {

    private final ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(1000);
    private DemoJPA demoJPA;

    @Async
    public void processEntries() {
        try(Stream<DemoModel> st = demoJPA.findEntries()) {
                CompletableFuture.allOf(st.map(entry -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                        doLogicMethod(entry),myPool))
                        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
        }
    }

    // logic methods go here

    @Override
    public void run() {
        processEntries();
    }
}
```

**DemoJpa**

```
@Repository
public interface DemoJPA extends JpaRepository<DemoModel,String> {
    @Query(value= "query here")
    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + 5),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true"),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
    })
    Stream<DemoModel> findEntries();
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know where to put `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` which is required because I stream data from db. Without I get this issue.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
```

My question is where do I need to have `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to make streaming query method work? Why putting it above `processEntires()` method not work?

**Update**

I have learnt that you don't need to implement Runnable Or Callable in a class to be able to run it in a separate thread. Instead, you can keep the class standard and simply call a function that you want to execute in the thread. So the below will work like a charm:

**Updated controller**

```
    @Autowired
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;
    @Autowired
    private DemoClass demoClass;

    @PostMapping("/demoPost")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doPost() {
        try {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> demoClass.processEntries());
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> anotherClass.doThings());
            t2.start();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Updated Demo class**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoClass {

    private final ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(1000);
    @Autowired
    private DemoJPA demoJPA;

    @Async
    public void processEntries() {
        try(Stream<DemoModel> st = demoJPA.findEntries()) {
                CompletableFuture.allOf(st.map(entry -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                        doLogicMethod(entry),myPool))
                        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
        }
    }

    // logic methods go here

}
```

So that answers "How can I make it work?" part of the question. However, I still would like to know why my initial implementation didn't work. `Thread(() -> demoClass.processEntries())` is a shortcut to this:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                // logic goes here
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // executable method goes here
                }
            });
```

So the difference is me putting the above code in a separate class. Yet it is not the same. Wonder if anyone could explain why is this the case? I suspect when implementing Runnable, the class that implements it gets changed somehow, but I am yet to find out what precisely is the problem.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but why did you put "implements Runnable" in your question title? Why would you expect the methods in a class that implements Runnable to behave any differently from methods in a class that doesn't implement Runnable?

Comment: @SolomonSlow because before Runnable everything worked fine. What I used to do when I only had this class (so there was no need for multithreading) the `run()` would replaced with `execute()` method (a standard method which I would annotate with the @Transactional) that will be called from the controller when autowiring DemoClass. But once I made DemoClass to implement Runnable, it refuses to work.

Comment: Simply adding `implements Runnable` to a class definition and renaming a `void execute()` method to be `void run()` won't ever make anything break. You did those things because you were _forced_ to do them because you changed the way your program _uses_ the class. In this case, apparently because you are using the class as the target of a `Thread`.  I don't know Spring. I don't know what the error message means. I don't know whether simply moving the method call into its own thread made any difference or not. I Hope somebody else can answer. Sorry I can't.